# Magento 2: How to get category image?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, frontend

I want to display the category image of the category.I have a phtml file and is called in cms home page.

```
<?php 
$subcats = array(99,189);
$imageBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\ListProduct');

foreach($subcats as $cat_id){
    //echo $cat_id;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
    $categoryImage = $imageBlock->getImage($category, 'category_page_list');
    echo 'dfdf'.$category->getName();
    //$productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($category);
    echo 'ssds'.$categoryImage;

}
```

But it is not displaying the image and getting an error.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should add the text of the error you get?

Answer (score 7):

I have Used This code to get Category images in my code Please look at these

```
<?php
    $category = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($item->getId());
    $_outputhelper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
        $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
    }
?>
```

Comment: yup absolutely.it is working code @aravind

Comment: @PranayK How can i get products images using sku?

Comment: @Learing_Coder, I'm struggling in getting the category image, Can you please help me? I have tried your code in phtml file but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

To get Category Image url:

```
<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>
```

And use it in `<img>` tag like

```
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

And get Alternate Image url:

```
echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); 
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code. just pass the category id fetch the image

use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;

```
public function getCategoryImage($categoryId)
{
    $categoryIdElements = explode('-', $categoryId);
    $category           = $this->categoryRepository->get(end($categoryIdElements));
    $categoryImage       = $category->getImageUrl();

    return $categoryImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View Modal (CategoryList.php)

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class CategoryList implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $categoryFactory;
    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    private $category;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $categoryFactory,
        Category $category
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getList()
    {
        $collection = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $items = [];
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active', ['eq' => 1]);
        foreach ($collection as $key => $categoryData) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
            try {
                $category = $this->category->load($categoryData->getID());
                $items[$key]['image'] = $category->getImageUrl();
                $items[$key]['name'] = $category->getName();
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

in your_layout.xml file

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::template.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="category_list" xsi:type="object">\Ktpl\CategoryCms\ViewModel\CategoryList</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

in your template.phtml file

```
<?php

/** @var $viewModel \Ktpl\CategoryCms\ViewModel\CategoryList */

$viewModel = $block->getCategoryList();
$categories = $viewModel->getList();

?>
<div class="home-cat-wrap">
    <div class="category">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <div class="cat-item">
                <div class="cat-img">
                    <img src="<?= $category['image'] ? $category['image'] : "http://demo.link" ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <h4><a href="#"><?= $category['name'] ?></a></h4>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="view-more"><a class="action primary">View More Categories</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing here to include helper, you need to use `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output` helper. See this link for help. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239192/show-category-with-images-in-homepage-magento2) and [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-helpers-in-magento-2/) to know. How to Create and Use Helpers in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

**[Magento 2.4.x]**

> **You can use the below function to get the category media image URL.**

```
/**
 * @category Msquare
 * @package Msquare_CategoryImageSlider
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

 ...............................................................
 ...............................................................
 ...............................................................

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image
 */
protected $categoryImage;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo
 */
protected $fileInfo;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
 */
protected $imageHelperFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
 */
protected $assetRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
 */
protected $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...............................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Image $categoryImage,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo $fileInfo,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository,
    ...............................................................
) {
    ...............................................................
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->categoryImage = $categoryImage;
    $this->fileInfo = $fileInfo;
    $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
    $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
    ...............................................................
}

public function getCategoryImage($categoryData, $attributeCode)
{
    $imageLink = null;
    $fileName = $categoryData->getData($attributeCode);
    if (($fileName) && ($this->fileInfo->isExist($fileName))) {
        $imageLink = $this->categoryImage->getUrl($categoryData, $attributeCode); //get category image
    } else {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create();
        $imageLink = $this->assetRepository->getUrl($imageHelper->getPlaceholder('image')); // get default placeholder image
    }

    return $imageLink;
}

public function getCategoryData($categoryId)
{
  return $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
```

> **After that you need to call the above function into your related phtml file like  below:**

```
$categoryData = $block->getCategoryData(4);
$categoryImage = $block->getCategoryImage($categoryData, 'image'); // you can also add your custom category image atribute
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried following so that it does not affect performance and you need to call the category model seprately

Open in root of magento 2.2

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php
```

On line750ish

Add

```
->addAttributeToSelect(
    'image'
)
```

or replace function

```
 /**
     * Return child categories
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function getChildrenCategories($category)
    {
        $collection = $category->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
            'url_key'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'image'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'all_children'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'is_anchor'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'is_active',
            1
        )->addIdFilter(
            $category->getChildren()
        )->setOrder(
            'position',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
        )->joinUrlRewrite();

        return $collection;
    }
```