# Magento 2 - How to get image of sub categories?

Tags: magento2, category, catalog

I need to get an image of subCategory.

```
$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($subcategories as $var) {
    print_r($var->getData())
}
```

I get every data other than category image.

```
    Array
(
    [entity_id] => 12
    [attribute_set_id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 11
    [created_at] => 2018-06-26 08:26:17
    [updated_at] => 2018-06-26 11:45:37
    [path] => 1/2/11/12
    [position] => 1
    [level] => 3
    [children_count] => 4
    [is_active] => 1
    [request_path] => men/tops-men.html
    [name] => Tops
    [url_key] => tops-men
    [is_anchor] => 1
)
```

the array conatin this data.

Comment: Follow this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166487/magento-2-how-to-get-category-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code :**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();

foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
    $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
    $_category->getImageUrl()
}
```

**See More** : [here](https://chetansanghani.wordpress.com/2017/06/23/magento-2-how-to-get-sub-category-of-current-category-in-magento2/)

Comment: Objectmanager and LSD. Both bad approaches.

Answer (score 0):

$imageUrl = $var->getImageUrl();

Comment: there is no ImageUrl in the array