# How to display category image in Megamenu?

Tags: magento2.3, topmenu, megamenu, category-image

I want to display the category image in mega menu(which we have created using html) but not success.

I have no idea, how to make this work so I'm here and hoping someone can help me with this.

Below is my code for your reference:

**Code in phtml file:**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
/**
* Top menu for store
*
* @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
*/
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/cart.css')?>">
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
/**
* Top menu for store
*
* @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
*/
?>
<header class="headers">
  <div class="header-inrs">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menus contenedor-menu">
        <ul class="clearfix backcolor designmenu">
          <div class="totalmobilelog">
            <div class="lo">
              <a href="" >
                <b class="clsml">
                  <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true">
                  </i>Login
                </b>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="si">
              <a href="" >
                <b class="clsml">
                  <i class="fa fa-registered" aria-hidden="true">
                  </i>Sign Up
                </b>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
foreach ($categories as $category):
?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath();?>">
              <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
            </a>
            <ul class="subc">
              <?php
$subCategories = $block->getCategoryById($category->getId());
foreach ($subCategories->getChildrenCategories() as $subCategory):
?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getRequestPath();?>">
                  <?php echo $subCategory->getName(); ?>
                  <?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>
                </a>
              </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php echo $block->getSubcategories($subCategories); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Code in Block file:**

```
<?php
namespace Butterfly\Megamenu\Block;
class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $categoryFactory;
protected $_catalogLayer;
protected $_categoryRepository;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,     
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,        
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,        
array $data = []
) {
$this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;   
$this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
parent::__construct(
$context,          
$data
);
}
public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
{
return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
}
public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
{
return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
public function  getSubcategories($categories) {
$array= '<ul class="child">';
foreach($categories->getChildrenCategories() as $category) {
$array .= '<li>'.
'<a href="' .$category->getRequestPath().'">' .
$category->getName() . "</a>\n";
if($category->hasChildren()) {
$children = $this->getCategoryById($category->getId());
$array .=  $this->getSubcategories($children);
}
$array .= '</li>';
}
return  $array . '</ul>';
}
}
```

1.[image]

2. [image]

Comment: have you got solution?

Comment: @RonakChauhan, No, still I'm looking for the solution. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: it's simple, you can have category image with $category object so use it below category name

Comment: @RonakChauhan, Can you please elaborate what you're trying to explain? Please give me example snippet

Answer (score 0):

To get Category Image url:

```
<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>
```

And use it in `<img>` tag like

```
<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

And get Alternate Image url:

```
echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); 

<img src="<?php  echo $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image'); ?>" />
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working. You can see in my code, I have put <?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>

Comment: Try to above code for get category image I hope it's work for you

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

Magento core function is available in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` file and it is called getImageUrl, code snippet can be seen below -:

```
/**
 * Get image url by attribute code.
 *
 * @param string $attributeCode
 * @return string
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getImageUrl($attributeCode = 'image')
{
    $url = false;
    $image = $this->getData($attributeCode);
    if ($image) {
        if (is_string($image)) {
            $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . 'catalog/category/' . $image;
        } else {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while getting the image url.')
            );
        }
    }

    return $url;
}
```

If you are using your own class then you need to add `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory` in the constructor and call the function below to get full category image path

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$fullCategoryPath = $category->getImageUrl();
echo $fullCategoryPath
```

Method 2

If you already have category image name then you can write your own function to return full category image path using the following snippet

```
/**
  * Get image url by imagename.
  *
  * @param string $image
  * @return string
  * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  */
 protected function getImageUrl($image)
 {
     $url = $image;
     if ($image) {
         if (is_string($image)) {
             $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                     \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                 ) . 'catalog/category/' . $image;
         } else {
             throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                 __('Something went wrong while getting the image url.')
             );
         }
     }

     return $url;
 }
```

Hope this article helped you in some way. Please leave us your comment and let us know what do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Block file:

```
<?php
namespace Butterfly\Megamenu\Block;
class Categorylist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
protected $_categoryHelper;
protected $categoryFactory;
protected $_catalogLayer;
protected $_categoryRepository;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,     
\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,        
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,        
array $data = []
) {
$this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;   
$this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
parent::__construct(
$context,          
$data
);
}
public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
{
return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted , $asCollection, $toLoad);
}
public function getCategoryById($categoryId) 
{
return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
public function  getSubcategories($categories) {
$array= '<ul class="child">';
foreach($categories->getChildrenCategories() as $category) {
$array .= '<li>'.
'<img src="'. $category->getImageUrl() . '" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"><a href="' .$category->getRequestPath().'">' .
$category->getName() . "</a>\n";
if($category->hasChildren()) {
$children = $this->getCategoryById($category->getId());
$array .=  $this->getSubcategories($children);
}
$array .= '</li>';
}
return  $array . '</ul>';
}
}
```

Check this code and try to get imageUrl.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried as you suggested and it seems working. Please see attached screenshot. But I want to show the image as per in the second screenshot. To do that I have to put the same code in phtml file. Am I right?

Comment: No, I don't think you need to change in phtml file, Block file will work, just place image at correct place in <li> element

Comment: Ok. Let me try. I have uploaded category image but still I can only see the alt text instead of image. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Also, I'm getting "Unknown image src" in console so that I'm not getting the image instead I'm getting only the alt text.

Comment: try with this: $category->getImageUrl('category_alternate_image')

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166487/magento-2-how-to-get-category-image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99337/discussion-between-ronak-chauhan-and-siva).