# How to select image from categories collection?

Tags: magento2, category, collection

I have entity

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $categoryCollection
```

And I'm trying following

```
$categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

but this doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: It should work, ensure that \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection` inject at your class .

Comment: `public function __construct(
  ....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $catalogCategoryCollectionFactory,
....
    ) {
        $this->catalogCategoryCollectionFactory= $catalogCategoryCollectionFactory;
    }
   public function getMyCategoryCollection()
{
 $categoryCollection =$this->catalogCategoryCollectionFactory->create();
 $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
}`

Comment: Yes, it is injected

Comment: try with name file?

Comment: Which type of category image you want to get. It's parent category or child category?

Comment: [I asked a similar question that might help](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160357/getting-category-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a small debug and found out that addAttributeToSelect have the second parameter

```
public function addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)
```

In my case `catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_category` configuration option was disabled. So I think for disabled flat category joinType should be true. I've added the following

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState
```

to the constructor. And this works for me like a charm

```
if ($this->flatState->isAvailable()) {
    $this->categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
} else {
    $this->categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image', true);
}
```